# Dynamically changing the constraint of a view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to change the left constraint (guideline) of a view inside my ConstraintLayout on press of a button. My layout XML (relevant parts) looks like this:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:indeterminate="true"
  android:visibility="gone"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_bcrumbs_bottom"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_group_left"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/guideline_group_left"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="205dp"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/guideline_category_left"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="461dp"/>
```

Here, I want to change the progress bar's `constraintLeft_toLeftOf` property from `guideline_group_left` to `guideline_category_left` dynamically. Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have added the following lines to adjust the constraint (based on this link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Constraints_using_ConstraintSet)

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.connect(mProgressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.guideline_category_left, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
set.connect(mProgressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
```

However, after these changes, the progress bar does not show up at all. I feel like I am close, but am probably missing something.

**EDIT 2**

I realized I forgot to add the following line, which is why it did not work.

```
set.clone(mConstraintLayout);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### SOLUTION:

I managed to solve my issue with the following lines of code, it might help someone else if they face a similar problem.

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(mConstraintLayout);
set.connect(mProgressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.guideline_category_left, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
set.connect(mProgressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
```

Comment: Life savers come in small packages, thank for this answer!

Comment: really you are a life-saver, @epekel, hopefully google in the near future adds this feature to create fluent API in XML so it is configured easily